# how to run asynchronous queries with Spring

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-batch

I need to use asynchronous queries using Spring framework. I use Cassandra and Java driver from Datastax. How can call the executeAsync method and get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have in mind 3 possible solutions:

1. `executeAsync` returns `ResultSetFuture` which has `isDone` method, you can have `while loop with`!isDone`and jump to some block when it returns`true`in`isDone`
2. There is `addListener` in `ResultSetFuture` so you can register listener to be fired after `Future` computation is done

> Registers a listener to be run on the given executor. The listener
>   will run when the Future's computation is complete or, if the
>   computation is already complete, immediately.

3. You can try similar approach but using `ListenableFuture` from the Guava library since which `ResultSetFuture` extends like explained in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322510/is-there-a-good-way-to-check-whether-a-datastax-session-executeasync-has-throw)

I think 3rd option is way to go and cleanest.